# Homomorphism of group and homomorphism of subgroup question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $T: G \rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism with kernel $N$ ($T$ is onto) and let $K$ be a subgroup of $G'$.

Then, $T^{-1}(K)$ is subgroup of $G$. So I think the mapping $T: T^{-1}(K) \rightarrow K$ is also a homomorphism with kernel $N$, because all the elements of $N$ are in $T^{-1}(K)$.

So it gives rise to an isomorphism $m$ such that $m: T^{-1}(K)/N \rightarrow K$, since $T$ is onto.

Is my argument right?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your argument is correct.  Note that the map $m$ is not only onto, it is also injective (because you have factored out the kernel of $T$), so $m$ is an isomorphism.

The map you've defined is actually the restriction of the map one gets from the [first isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem) to the subgroup of $G/N$ that corresponds to $K$.

Comment: What if T is not onto map? does that change the above statemnet?

Comment: You still get an injective map $m$, but $m$ might not be onto.